# How set time duration for local notification

Tags: iphone, ios

in my iPhone application I need to show local notification. I would like to know is it possible to set a  time interval for local notification  showing on the screen? For example I would like to show local notification during 20 seconds. I know that local notification is showing while sound is playing. But also I have found out that it is not possible to repeat local notification sound: [UILocalNotification repeat sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642637/uilocalnotification-repeat-sound)

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of expiry with local notifications. You tell them to fire and it's up to the user to dismiss or interact with them.

With regard to making the sound last 20 seconds (apart from the fact I would delete this app if it insists on playing 20 notification sounds!), let's say for example your current sound lasts 5 seconds, you could copy paste that sound 4 times in to one file and just play that. I think there is a maximum sound length of 30s, but I can't find the documentation supporting this.

Comment: He could actually make a short beep sound with 19secs of silence if it's true that the notification stays on screen as long as the sound is playing…

Comment: The problem is that's not true Engin. It stays on screen until the user interacts with it, potentially forever.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad English.
You can repeat local notification only with NSCalendarUnit value. Or reset him (notification) and set new when old notification worked in method (application:didReceiveLocalNotification:).  For this you can add your own dictionary to notification object userInfo value and handle him later when notifiction received in this method. But this method can't work in background mode when app is not runned, or not runned by tap on notification alert. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can set duration by changing `notify.firedate` after every 20 seconds.

for maintaining every 20 seconds- you can use timer

Answer (score 0):

If it is about repeating the notification sound, then you can do it in this way:

```
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm =[[UILocalNotification alloc] 
                                       init];
    if (notifyAlarm)
    {
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = nil;
        notifyAlarm.soundName=@"phone.wav";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody =@"value";
        notifyAlarm.alertAction=@"value";
        notifyAlarm.hasAction=YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notifyAlarm];
        [notifyAlarm release];

        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive || state==UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            [self backgroundHandlerToPlayCallTone];
        }
    }

-(void)backgroundHandlerToPlayCallTone {
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTaskToPlayCallTone = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:self->bgTaskToPlayCallTone];
        self->bgTaskToPlayCallTone = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}];

// Start the long-running task 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self startCallTone];
    [app endBackgroundTask:self->bgTaskToPlayCallTone];
    self->bgTaskToPlayCallTone= UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}); 
}

-(void) startCallTone {
if(audioPlayer !=nil) {
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [audioPlayer release];
    audioPlayer=nil;
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phone" ofType:@"wav"]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=10;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
//[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, sizeof(allowMixing),&allowMixing);

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[audioPlayer play];
}
```